# How to join three table by laravel eloquent model Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I searched on the internet for my problem but I couldn't find an answer.
I found a tutorial on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165410/how-to-join-three-table-by-laravel-eloquent-model), but for my example it didn't worked.

When I run the following code, it returns `NULL`:

```
$data['lessons']->student
```

What i want to get:

ID | Date | User.firstname | Teacher.firstname

My code:

I have 3 Tables:

- lesson {id, date, fk_students_id, fk_teachers_id}
- student {id, firstname}
- teacher{id, firstname}

Model *Lesson.php*:

```
public function student(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Student');
}

public  function teacher(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Teacher');
}
```

Model *Student.php*:

```
public function lessons(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Lesson', 'fk_students_id');
}
```

Model *Teacher.php*:

```
public function lessons(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Lesson', 'fk_teachers_id');
}
```

And in the *Controller*:

```
$data['lessons'] = Lesson::with(['student', 'teacher'])->first();
return var_dump($data['lessons']->student);
```

**UPDATE**
*Output* of `dd($data);`:

```
array:1 [
"lessons" => Lesson {#303 
#connection: null
#table: null
#primaryKey: "id"
#perPage: 15
+incrementing: true
+timestamps: true
#attributes: array:10 [
  "id" => 1
  "date" => "2015-07-25"
  "start" => "12:30:00"
  "end" => "13:00:00"
  "fk_students_id" => 1
  "fk_teachers_id" => 1
  "lesson_array" => "[{"id":"1", "result":"0"},{"id":"2", "result":"1"},{"id":"15", "result":"2"}]"
  "slug" => "562153eae355e"
  "created_at" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  "updated_at" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
]
#original: array:10 [
  "id" => 1
  "date" => "2015-07-25"
  "start" => "12:30:00"
  "end" => "13:00:00"
  "fk_students_id" => 1
  "fk_teachers_id" => 1
  "lesson_array" => "[{"id":"1", "result":"0"},{"id":"2", "result":"1"},{"id":"15", "result":"2"}]"
  "slug" => "562153eae355e"
  "created_at" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
  "updated_at" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
]
#relations: array:2 [
  "student" => null
  "teacher" => null
]
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#appends: []
#fillable: []
#guarded: array:1 [
  0 => "*"
]
#dates: []
#casts: []
#touches: []
#observables: []
#with: []
#morphClass: null
+exists: true
}
]
```

Thank you for you help!

Comment: remove `return var_dump($data['lessons']->student);` and put  `dd($data);`, post result please

Comment: @AndreL i have updated the post. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see,

```
#relations: array:2 [
  "student" => null
  "teacher" => null
]
```

Are both null, is because of foreign keys name.

So you should set them on the model:

```
public function student(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Student', 'fk_teachers_id', 'id');
}

public  function teacher(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Teacher', 'fk_students_id','id');
}
```

Comment: Could laravel know that `fk_students_id` is a foreign key? do laravel know this pattern? I've allways declaring `local_key`'s and `parent_key`'s. just asking @Rudie.