# join three table relation by laravel eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I have three table which is explained below

## User

```
id
email
password
```

## specialities

```
id
name
active
```

## results

```
id
specialitie_id
user_id
result
color
```

i am trying to relate results with the rest of the 2 tables, but i don't know how to do it, below is my model relation, please correct me if there's any issue, i can't fetch the data due to having wrong relation

Result Model

```
class Result extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function speciality()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Speciality::class);
    }
}
```

User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{

    public function result()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Result::class);
    }

}
```

i am trying to expect a correct result of my relation database tables in laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `results` table is  [Intermediate Table Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns).use laravel `belongsToMany` method so no need to create results model.Treat results table as pivot table.

In User Model add relation like below

```
public function specialities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Speciality::class,'results')->withPivot('result','color');
}
```

Also read here [Many To Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: isn't it's one to many relationship? hasmany is not a correct so ?

Comment: @BenishFarooq its many to many.

Comment: to use **hasMany** correctly, the **user_id needs to be inside of Speciality::class**, but in your case you are saying 1 user can have many specialities, and 1 speciality can belong to many users... so the overall relationship is ManyToMany, and the documentation for some strange reason does not have ManyToMany as a category, that is why many new programmers have this confusion.

Comment: @KGG looking into this question don't you think it should have many to many as well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263954/how-to-join-three-table-by-laravel-eloquent-model-laravel-5

Comment: @BenishFarooq.that can also be done but better way is belongsToMany

Comment: For you "current" case, John is 100% correct but maybe the answer you are looking for and the way you designed the database is not matching. If you want, you could add (to your original question) some sample data, and logic of what you are trying to accomplish and why you want to have a Result model.

Comment: @KGG so far everything went good, he was correct, Many to many is correct way, last thing if i want to fetch data from the table result it should be done this way right? $result = User::with('specialities')->get();

Comment: @BenishFarooq yes.but you get result table data inside pivot key.you can dd($result->toArray()) to see result response

Comment: Absolutely, if you are satisfied with the information, please mark the answer of john as complete to help future coders find the right answer, and he would appreciate a thumbs up as well :D

Comment: @KGG everything went perfectly, thank you again for the help, i have one last question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75056160/laravel-fetch-intermediate-table-data-with-many-to-many-relationship