# Laravel fetch intermediate table data with many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I have 3 tables
`user, specialities & results`

results contain `specialitie_id, user_id`

I have create many-to-many relationship

Here's the relationship in user model

```
public function specialities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Speciality::class, 'results', 'user_id', 'specialitie_id')->withPivot('result', 'color');
    }
```

I want to fetch data from the result table based on `specialitie_id`

If my url is
`abc.com/result/5`

I have attached table structure as well,
[image]

it should show me result related to `specialitie_id` 5
I tried this but it doesn't work

```
$result = User::with('specialities')->where('id', 5)->get();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your current query:**

```
$result = User::with('specialities')->where('id', 5)->get();
```

> Is saying, give me all results where the **USER_ID** = 5 **WITH** all the specialities related to it.

---

**You are very close but did it backwards:**

```
//Give me all results where the SPECIALITY_ID = 5 
//WITH all the users related to it
$result = Speciality::with('users')->where('id', 5)->get();
```

> *Please note that the above is an array*

**Example of a Controller Function:**

```
public function results($id){
    $results = Speciality::with('users')->where('id', $id)->get(); 

    return view('user_specialities', compact('results'));
}
```

**Example view *user_specialities*:**

```
@foreach($results as $result)
    <p>Result: {{$result->result}}</p>
    <p>Formulary: {{$result->formulary}}</p>
    <p>Color: {{$result->color}}</p>
    <p>User ID: {{$result->user->id}}</p>
    <p>User Name: {{$result->user->name}}</p>
@endforeach
```

**Speciality Model:**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'results', 'specialitie_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('result', 'color');
}
```

**User Model:**

```
public function specialities()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Speciality::class, 'results', 'user_id', 'specialitie_id')->withPivot('result', 'color');
}
```

Comment: $result = Speciality::with('users')->where('id', 5)->get();  -< this doesn't return SPECIALITY_ID = 5 it return id of user.

Comment: please check https://www.dropbox.com/s/cw6pugq83clkp76/dd.png?dl=0

Comment: @BenishFarooq you are correct, my mistake, its because the relationship in the model is backwards, can you please check the Speciality Model and User Model - i changed the answer a little. It is actually returning the correct array of speciality, but not showing any users because of the mistake in the models

Comment: i can see the query is now corrected, one more thing when i fetch the information i am getting this error Attempt to read property "id" on null, i want to fetch information directly, $result->user->name, $result->result, $result->specialities->name

Comment: Currently its showing a collection of results, although in **dd()** image its showing 1 result, so for that case change **->get()** to **->first()** to bring out the first result from the collection. Then you can do **$result->name** or **$result->color** -- you can always take a look at how I did it in the blade example :)

Comment: thank you, all good, in template i try to run foreach loop but getting error Attempt to read property "formulary" on bool, yes i change get() to first ()

Comment: Very nice, okay, so "formulary" is inside the PIVOT TABLE in the database, but you are not able to access it, change your model to include it like this **withPivot('result', 'color', 'formulary')** then just make sure you are using it correctly in the blade like the rest of fields, anytime you want to access a new pivot field, you need to declare it in the model :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250967/discussion-between-kgg-and-benish-farooq).

Comment: @BenishFarooq if this answered your question, could you please mark it as complete :)

Comment: thank you, all good, i send you a message via chat could you please look in to it as well? i have resolved my issue, just wanted you to look at it and i would like to see how you can fix the issue

Comment: possible for you to help me with this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75118359/how-to-search-value-in-collection-and-merge-model-in-laravel