# Laravel 5 - Join 3 tables in eloquent with the combination result

Tags: mysql, laravel, model, eloquent, laravel-5

```
**Table Task**
id
project_id
user_id

**Table Project**
id
project_name

**Table User**
id
fname
lname
```

I have checked with the below link and its works fine for table joining.

[How to join three table by laravel eloquent model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165410/how-to-join-three-table-by-laravel-eloquent-model/29166530#29166530)

But I want to retrieve the below Task result. Is it possible.

```
id
project_id
project_name
user_id
fname
lname
```

I want this result for each task data by combining project & user table.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set up your models and relationships for Task, Project and User?

If you have set up your models with correct eloquent relationships, you can try this:

```
$tasks = Task::with('project','user')->get();
```

This assumes that in your Task model, you have defined your eloquent function properly, e.g. if a task belongs to a project, and also belongs to a user:

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Comment: Yes,  I have set up models and relationships for Task, Project and User. But i did not set correctly. So its not working. Now I have used your correct eloquent relationship. Now its working fine, thanks for your answer. Thank you very much.