# laravel 5.1 eloquent select with prefix joined table

Tags: laravel, select, eloquent, prefix

I have this query

```
$sales = Sales::join('customer', 'customer.id', '=', 'sales.customer_id')
->join('cashier', 'cashier.id', '=', 'sales.cashier_id')
->first();
```

how can i select each table with prefix so i can call like this :

- $order->customer_name
- $order->cashier_name

with my query above, i only get one name row because each table have same column name `name`, what
i want is to give prefixed in each table i call like `customer_`, `cashier_`, `sales_`

## Update

the result what i expect is like this

```
customer_name
customer_address
customer_phone
cashier_name
cashier_another_column
cashier_another_column2
sales_date
sales_another_column
sales_another_column2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the answer is you cannot do that. i usually only alias the same column name and get the rest with `*`. so your required to alias all same column name for solve the conflict

```
Sales::join('customer', 'customer.id', '=', 'sales.customer_id')
->join('cashier', 'cashier.id', '=', 'sales.cashier_id')
->select(['*', 'customer.name as customer_name', 'cashier.name as cashier_name'])
->get();
```

Comment: thanks maybe this is the best approach for me right now beside describing all column name one by one

Answer (score 0):

You have to use select and then you can give alias to your column names.

As example.

```
$sales = Sales::join('customer', 'customer.id', '=', 'sales.customer_id')
->join('cashier', 'cashier.id', '=', 'sales.cashier_id')
->select('customer.name as customer_name','cashier.name as cashier_name')
->first();
```

and so on you can select as many fields from database as you want and give them aliases.

Comment: yes i know this, but i don't want to select one by one, because i have many column for that query, so like i state above, i want to use `*`. for example i want to select like this `customer.* as customer_` so all my customer column is prefixes with `customer_`

Comment: Then you can use [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) Accessors and mutators. 
so in your Customer model if you want name then 
`code`public function getNameAttribute($value) {
        return "customer_".$value;
    }

Comment: the problem is when i run my query without alias then my similiar column name will replaced each other. i only get one name from cashier, doesn't get name from customer

Comment: @martiendt Use raw queries and Join by Eloquent models and in models use mutators as i mentioned in above column then you will get desired result. 

Or you can use relations as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165410/how-to-join-three-table-by-laravel-eloquent-model

Answer (score 0):

```
Use get() method and add alias to column name. You can add toArray() after get() to get result in array.
$sales = Sales::join('customer', 'customer.id', '=', 'sales.customer_id')
    ->join('cashier', 'cashier.id', '=', 'sales.cashier_id')
    ->get(['customer.name as customer_name', 'cashier.name as cashier_name'])
    ->toArray();
```

Comment: how to make an alias for all column ? i want to alias all column like this `customer_` and i have 10 - 20 column per table, so i don't want to add alias one by one