# Laravel 5.3 query to get results from 4 tables which has connections via Foreign Key

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm using Laravel 5.3. I've 4 tables.
Default `Users` table. `Departments`, `Position`, `Employees` tables.

`Users` table has `ID | Email | Password`

`Departments` table has `ID | Department | User_Id` - Here `User_Id` is foreign key comes from `Users` table's `ID`

`Positions` table has `ID | Position | Department_Id` - Here `Department_Id` is foreign key comes from `Departments` table's `ID`

`Employees` table has `ID | Employee | Position_Id`  - Here `Position_Id` is foreign key comes from `Positions` table's `ID`

User can have multiple `Departments`. `Departments` can have multiple `Positions`, `Positions` can have multiple `Employees`. So, if user is different, how can i retrieve all data from all 4 tables which that user had created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$departments = Department::where('user_id', $id)
    ->with('positions', 'positions.employees')
    ->get();
```

Another way is to build simple queries:

```
$departments = Department::where('user_id', $id)->get();
$positions = Position::whereIn('department_id', $departments->pluck('id'));
$employees = Employee::whereIn('position_id', $positions->pluck('id'));
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29166530/3866364
   I tried to it this way, but cannot create the relation properly.

Comment: What do you mean by difference? If your relations do not work, please post another question and add your relations code and exact names of foreign keys (case sensitive).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What i mean is, your answer has only Query. But in the other Question's answer i shared above comment, has used Model (used for example OneToMany, ManyToOne etc). So, whats the benefits of using query like urs or using Modal relations?

Comment: Thanks for rephrasing, now I get it. There is no difference, because in my example (first solution) I've used relations `positions()` and `employees()`. We will need to setup those to make first solution code work. Just add these relations (both are `hasMany()` I believe) in appropriate models.

Comment: so, 2nd solution doesnt require this relations in models?

Comment: Yes, second solution will work without defined relations.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going mark your solution as answer anyway. But just another question, what if i want show all positions in a (blade) html table and also show which position is under which Department and department under which Company. How can i do that? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In this case it's much more convinient to use relations. But if you don't want to use relations, you can use `where()` to work with collections. Just as an example: iterate over departments as usual `@foreach ($departments as $department)`, inside that loop iterate over positions with something like `@foreach ($positions->where('department_id', $department->id) as $position)` etc.