# Laravel Eloquent: How to select from multiple tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel and the Eloquent ORM that it provides but I'm struggling to select the data I need.  I have 3 Models

- House
- Occupants
- Job

A house can have multiple occupants and I can easily get these using the following.

```
$house= House::find($house_id);
$occupants = $house->occupants()->where('active', 1)->get();
```

This works nicely but I also want to select the job of each occupant.  I've got this as a one to one relationship but the jobs are in a seperate table.

Is there a way to also **select the related job** for each occupant from the jobs table efficiently?  I'm guessing it would be something like this

```
$occupants_and_jobs = $house->occupants()->where('active', 1)->job()->get();
```

Comment: You can check :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165410/how-to-join-three-table-by-laravel-eloquent-model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just try what you are suggesting and see what happens. 
You can also do some [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) of the relationships

```
$house = House::with(["occupants","occupants.job"])->find($house_id);
foreach ($house->occupants as $occupant) {
     print_r($occupant->job);
}
```

As @AlexeyMezenin if you need to constrain the relationship then you need to (as the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) suggest under *Constraining Eager Loads*) do:

```
$house = House::with(["occupants" => function ($query) { 
    $query->where("active","=",1); 
},"occupants.job"])->find($house_id);
foreach ($house->occupants as $occupant) {
    print_r($occupant->job);
}
```

Now the fine-print: Laravel will include "with" relationships in the order it finds them and also include all intermediate relationships of the nesting, e.g. `::with("occupants.job")` implies `::with(["occupants","occupants.job"])` however if you already have set a previous relationship then it is maintained (which is how this works). `occupants` will not be overwritten when `occupants.job` is set.

Comment: This query will load all the data, even where active is not 1.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin damn, i missed that.

Comment: Cool. Also, you shouldn't return `$query`, it should be just `$query->....`

Answer (score 1):

This query will load all occupants with `active = 1` and their jobs:

```
House::with(['occupants' => function($q) {
    $q->where('active', 1);
}, 'occupants.job'])->find($house_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete way to to search data from different tables in laravel:

Route:

```
Route::get('/systems/search', 'SearchController@search')->name('project-search');
```

Try this way in your searchController:

```
 public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $data = DB::table('projects as p')->select('p.*','u.first_name', 'u.last_name')
        ->join('users as u','p.user_id','=','u.id');
        if( $request->input('search')){
            $data = $data->where('p.title', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->search . "%")
            ->orWhere('p.description', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->search . "%")
            ->orWhere('u.first_name', 'LIKE', "%" . $request->search . "%")
            ->orderBy('p.created_at', 'desc');
        }
        $data = $data->paginate(16);
        return view('systems.search', compact('data'));
      
    }
```

And receive those data in your blade like this way:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
<h3>List of Results</h3>
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
<th>title</th>
<th>description</th>
<th>creator</th>
<th>category</th>
</tr>

@foreach($data as $search)
<tr>
<td>{{ $search->title }}</td>
<td>{{ $search->description }}</td>
<td>{{ $search->first_name }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</table>
{{ $data->appends(request()->except('page'))->links() }}
</div>
```

search box input field:

```
<div class="input-group input_search" style="width: 100%">
                                    <input style="border-radius: 20px" type="text" class="form-control search"
                                        placeholder="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" name="search" id="search"
                                        value="{{Request::get('title')}}">
```