# Can I somehow also get the usernames of the people who have commented on an image if I only have their ids in my comments table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

My comments table has the following columns:

```
id, user_id, image_id, comment
```

Currently I'm getting all comments that belong to a specific image like this:

```
$comments = Comment::where('image_id', $id)->get();
```

And then I can easily display the comments on the view to which I pass the `$comments` variable. However, I can only display the id of the user who has posted the comment but that wouldn't make much sense so I'm trying to display the username instead.

Since I don't save the username of the user who has posted a comment in the comments table, I can't access it from `$comments` as of now. Is there a way to somehow add an extra key-value pair to `$comments` that would contain the username of the user based on his `id`?

Comment model:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function images(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Image');
    }

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

User model:

```
class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you should have a table/model for the `User` objects.

If so, you can [Eager Load](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the relationship. To accomplish this, define the relationship in your model:

**app/Comment.php**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

> Note: given that this is the reverse of a `hasMany` relationship (`belongsTo`), you should name this functions in singular: a `Comment` *belongs to* a unique `User`.

Then in your controller:

```
$comments = Comment::with('users')->where('image_id', $id)->get();
```

This will include the `user` object inside every `comment`. Of course, you can limit the user attributes returned to the view but you get te idea.

---

To know more about this, check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Comment: I'm trying to make it work but I might be doing something wrong. I've added my models to my question as well. I do believe I have the relationships done. How would I access the author in my blade view if everything is done correctly?

Comment: I&#39;ve updated the relationships in my response to match yours. @bobimaru you do this: `$comments-&gt;first() -&gt;users-&gt;name`

Comment: I keep getting "Trying to get property 'username' of non-object" after doing <p>{{ $comment->users->username }}</p>. $comment is singular because it is in a foreach loop

Comment: Also after dd($comments), I saw that #relations: array:1 [▼
        "users" => null
      ]. I believe that might be related to the problem.

Comment: @Bobimaru `$comment->users` is collection or array of object. Should be tried with `$comment->{users[0]}->username`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Join similar to connect both tables!

```
 $comments = DB::table('comment')
        ->join('user', 'comment.user_id', '=', 'user.id')
        ->select('comment.*', 'user.name')
        ->where(image_id, $id)
        ->get();
```

A related question with eloquent specifics
[How to join three table by laravel eloquent model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165410/how-to-join-three-table-by-laravel-eloquent-model)

Comment: You need to define a many to many relationship within your Comment entity to link to users by default https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Comment: My user model has a hasMany relationship with comments and my comment model has a belongsTo relationship with user. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Don’t your comments have a property with the user objects that belong to them? If your model contains the given relationship then for a comment you should be able to access comment->user->name