# Why am I getting "Trying to get property 'username' of non-object" when trying to access "$comment->users->username"?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get the usernames of the users who have posted comments, however, I keep getting "Trying to get property 'username' of non-object" error. I believe my relationships are done correctly but I might be wrong.

My tables:

```
Table: Users
Columns: id, username, password

Table: Comments
Columns: id, user_id, image_id, comment
```

Comment model:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

User model:

```
class User extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

I'm getting the comments like this:

```
$comments = Comment::with('users')->where('image_id', $id)->get();
```

And then trying to loop through them in the view like this:

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
    <p>{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
    <p>{{ $comment->users->username }}</p>
@endforeach
```

And when I dd($comments), I see:

```
 #relations: array:1 [▼
        "users" => null
 ]
```

I'm not sure why is it null though.

Comment: Why? Because `$comment->users` is not an object

Comment: As far as I understand, I could do that based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165410/how-to-join-three-table-by-laravel-eloquent-model?noredirect=1&lq=1 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Your relations is correct. maybe you db is not correct. Check comments table user_id column is null or not??4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
    <p>{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
    <p>{{ !empty($comment->users->username) ? $comment->users->username : '' }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Also I suggest you change you relations name `users` to `user`

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Get comments

```
$comments = Comment::with('user')->where('image_id', $id)->get();
```

And in view

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
    <p>{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
    @if(!empty($comment->user))
        <p>{{ $comment->user->username }}</p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: are you try it??

Answer (score 1):

try this way :

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
    <p>{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
    <p>{{ $comment->users["username"] }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($comments as $comment)
<p>{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
<p>{{ optional($comment->users)->username}}</p> 
@endforeach
```

Try this approach.