# How to fetch specified attributes from $this->belongsTo() in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I want to fetch some particular field from table rather than complete attributes in `$this->belongsTo();` I can't use select('field_name') or `pluck('field_name')` or `DB::raw(count(),avg())` etc with belongsTo,hasTo() ..... 
How i solve this problem?

I can't use

```
$this->belongsTo()->select('fiel_name')
```

or

```
$this->belongsTo()->pluck('fiel_name')
```

Please check the reference : [How to join three table by laravel eloquent model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165410/how-to-join-three-table-by-laravel-eloquent-model)

In the above reference, They fetched all attributes in blengsTo(), But in my case i have to fetch only particular attributes.

Comment: This should work fine, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: You can always do this `Model::with(['relation'=>function($query){
        $query->select('id','field_name');
    }])->get()`

Comment: its not working.... please check the same problem Link : -https://laravel.io/forum/09-03-2014-how-can-i-do-this-this-hasmany-select-where

Comment: what is issue you face for @AchrafKhouadja 's solution?

Comment: try https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources

Comment: Please check the reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165410/how-to-join-three-table-by-laravel-eloquent-model

In the above reference, They fetched all attributes in blengsTo(), But in my case i have to fetch only particular attributes.

Comment: @HarizMohammed try this. `return $this->belongsTo("Model", "foreign_key", "local_key")->select(['fiel_name', 'field_name_2'])` mention foreign and local key in your Model. otherwise provide Models, and accessing syntax

Comment: @ThataL i tried like this 'return $this->belongsTo('Projects\Models\Buser','user_id')->select(['user_name']);'  But its result shows  **Buser=Null**.

Comment: have you added both foreing &b local key ?

Comment: i have tried . but no results found

Comment: I have tested. it works fine. may be in your model you write something incorrect. provide Model code.

Comment: This is my model:-                                                                                               
 `<?php

namespace Projects\Models;

class Article extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{

protected $table = 'articles';

public function buser()
{
return $this->belongsTo('Projects\Models\Buser','user_id');
}

public function category()
{
return $this->belongsTo('Projects\Models\Category','categories_id');
}
}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it like this

```
$this->belongsTo('Model')->select(array('field_name'));
```

where `Model` can be for example User etc.