# how to write multiple join in laravel using eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

I am learning laravel. I want to write following query in laravel using eloquent:

```
 select b.branch_name, w.branch_work_name from branches AS b, branch_work_metadata AS w, branch_work_lookup AS bw where b.branch_id = bw.branch_id AND w.branch_work_id = bw.branch_work_id
```

Above query works perfectly in phpmysql

I have Models for each table as follows:

Table: branches --- Model: Branch

Table: branch_work_metadata --- Model: BranchWorkMetadata

Table: branch_work_lookup --- Model: BranchWorkLookup

When I tried to write above query in laravel it gives me error

```
 $branch = DB::table('branches as b', 'branch_work_metadata as w', 'branch_work_lookup as bw')
               ->select('b.branch_name','w.branch_work_name')
               ->join('b.branch_id','=','bw.branch_id')
               ->join('w.branch_work_id','=','bw.branch_work_id') 
               ->get();
```

Above gives me error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'b.branch_id' doesn't exist (SQL: select `b`.`branch_name`, `w`.`branch_work_name` from `branches` as `b` inner join `b`.`branch_id` on `=` = `bw`.`branch_id` inner join `w`.`branch_work_id` on `=` = `bw`.`branch_work_id`)
```

Also tried following:

```
$branch = BranchWorkLookup::Join('branches.branch_id','=','branch_work_lookup.branch_id')
                ->Join('branch_work_metadata.branch_work_id','=','branch_work_lookup.branch_work_id')
                ->select(
                    'branches.branch_name',
                    'branch_work_name'
                    )
                ->get();
```

giving error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'branches.branch_id' doesn't exist (SQL: select `branches`.`branch_name`, `branch_work_name` from `branch_work_lookup` inner join `branches`.`branch_id` on `=` = `branch_work_lookup`.`branch_id` inner join `branch_work_metadata`.`branch_work_id` on `=` = `branch_work_lookup`.`branch_work_id`)
```

Whats going wrong? Not able to find solution. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If anybody knows, how to write in that query using eloquent please tell me. That will be helpful to me and everyone who will come across same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mix the old school join syntax with the modern version used by Laravel's query builder, which is also the version you should be using.  Try this instead:

```
$branch = DB::table('branches as b')
    ->select('b.branch_name', 'w.branch_work_name')
    ->join('branch_work_lookup as bw', 'b.branch_id', '=', 'bw.branch_id')
    ->join('branch_work_metadata as w', 'w.branch_work_id', '=', 'bw.branch_work_id')
    ->get();
```

To be clear, this is the raw MySQL query you should be using:

```
SELECT
    b.branch_name,
    w.branch_work_name
FROM branches AS b
INNER JOIN branch_work_lookup bw
    ON b.branch_id = bw.branch_id
INNER JOIN branch_work_metadata AS w
    ON w.branch_work_id = bw.branch_work_id;
```

Comment: giving me ```Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'bw.branch_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `b`.`branch_name`, `w`.`branch_work_name` from `branches` as `b` inner join `branch_work_metadata` as `w` on `b`.`branch_id` = `bw`.`branch_id` inner join `branch_work_lookup` as `bw` on `w`.`branch_work_id` = `bw`.`branch_work_id`)```

Comment: Try the updated answer; I had the order of join conditions swapped initially, it should work now.

Comment: yes. its working now. Can you please also tell me, how to write that using eloquent(using model name) not by query builder? Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know Eloquent syntax very well.

Comment: You can take a look at this tuto : https://www.larashout.com/using-joins-in-laravel-eloquent-queries.  And this reply : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165410/how-to-join-three-table-by-laravel-eloquent-model

Comment: small tip : the "=" is not mandatory. you can write : ->join('branch_work_lookup as bw', 'b.branch_id', 'bw.branch_id')