# Laravel Eloquent: joining tables and retrieving specific value?

Tags: php, html, database, laravel, eloquent

I am rather new to Laravel and I am working on a meal planning project. One of the functionalities I would like to have is to have a View to print off a table containing all the ingredients within a specific meal plan.

##### Meal Plan Table

- id
- MealPlan_ID
- Recipe_ID

##### Recipe Table

- id
- Recipe_Name
- etc...

##### Ingredients Table

- id
- Recipe_ID
- Ingredient_Name
- Amount

One Meal Plan has many Recipes. One Recipe has many Ingredients.

On the view that displays the meal plan, I would like to have a button like `Preview Ingredients Print list`, which then pulls up a view displaying all of the Ingredients associated with all of the Recipes in *that specific* meal plan.

I have tried having a request for the `MealPlan_ID` (the unique identifier for each individual meal plan, which has multiple recipe ID's), and then joining the tables together. Because both the Meal Plan table and Ingredients table have `Recipe_ID`, can the Recipe Table be left out altogether in the join?

```php
public function printpreviewingredients($MealPlan_ID)
{
    //take the Meal Plan ID, to then collect the correct Recipe ID's and all of the following ingredients.
    $ingredients = MealPlanDisplay::find($MealPlan_ID)
        ->join('recipeingredientsmain', 'recipeingredientsmain.recipe_id', '=', 'mealplan_main.Recipe_ID')
        ->get(['recipeingredientsmain.id', 'recipeingredientsmain.ingredientname', 'recipeingredientsmain.amount']);

    return view('MealPlanDisplay.printpreviewingredientslist', compact('ingredients'));
}
```

The `web.php` route is:

```
Route::get('printpreviewingredients/{$MealPlan_ID}', [MealPlanDisplayController::class, 'printpreviewingredients']);
```

The view `printpreviwingredientslist.blade.php` then contains a table with information `ingredients`:

```html
<thead class="bg-gray-50">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
            ID
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
            Recipe ID
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
            Ingredient Name
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
            Amount
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
    @foreach ($ingredients as $var)
        <tr>
            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
                {{$var->id}}
            </td>
            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
                {{$var->Recipe_Id}}
            </td>
            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
                {{$var->ingredientname}}
            </td>
            <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-right text-sm font-medium">
                {{$var->amount}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Unfortunately this returns a 404 error, with `page not found`. I'm not really sure how to approach this join and information retrieval with a three-table relationship. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm fairly new to Laravel myself. One thing you can check, inside the printpreviewingredients function, is add a `dd($ingredients);` before the return view, but do it with just a plain `->get();` with the query to see if the query is getting the expected data. If the route may have issues, you can check `php artisan route:list` at the command line to see if it has errors, or if not, that your route is listed.

Answer (score 0):

it is because you have defined an incorrect file in the return view. Please check your filename spelling.

For joining table using Laravel eloquent please follow this answer given below

[How to join three table by laravel eloquent model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165410/how-to-join-three-table-by-laravel-eloquent-model)